# How to implement schema per service and private tables in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, microservices

I am working on a ***microservices architecture*** using **NestJS**

I've read about many design patterns to implement ***microservices architecture***

Speaking of ***Database per service*** and ***Shared DB***

I made my decision on moving toward ***Shared DB*** because ***Database per service*** needs huge effort to implement integrations between these services and the app in-hand is not requiring that much scalability

Speaking of which and following this [link](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/database-per-service.html)

I've found two approaches for ***Shared DB*** approach and I am going to list all them:

- Private-tables-per-service – each service owns a set of tables that must only be accessed by that service
- Schema-per-service – each service has a database schema that’s private to that service

I searched on how to implement these approaches in `mongodb` or `mongoose` but I could not get any fulfilling result, so I'd appreciate any idea about it.

Comment: Did you figured out solution of this question??